# Populating multiple comboboxes in a single event

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm trying to populate a number of combo boxes in a formLoad method, but only the 1st one populates. in this same method the same stored procedures are called for Data Grids and work fine. Please see attached code:

```
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccessLayer dal = new DataAccessLayer();
        pnlEditCall.Visible = false;
        pnlEditInspection.Visible = false;
        pnlEditEquipment.Visible = false;
        #region Populate DataGrids
        dgvInspections.DataSource = dal.GetAllInspections();
        dgvCalls.DataSource = dal.GetAllCalls();
        dgvStaff.DataSource = dal.GetAllStaff();
        dgvLabs.DataSource = dal.GetAllLabs();
        dgvEquipment.DataSource = dal.GetAllEquipment();
        #endregion

        #region Populate ComboBoxes
        cmbInspectionStaff.DataSource = dal.GetAllStaff();
        cmbInspectionStaff.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cmbInspectionStaff.ValueMember = "[StaffID]";
        cmbCallStaff.DataSource = dal.GetAllStaff();
        cmbCallStaff.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cmbCallStaff.ValueMember = "[StaffID]";
        cmbCurrentLab.DataSource = dal.GetAllLabs();
        cmbCurrentLab.ValueMember = "[LabNo]";
        cmbCurrentLab.DisplayMember = "[LabNo]";
        #endregion
     }
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not here but in the `dal` methods

Comment: Are your calls to the DataAccessLayer class returning any results the 2nd or 3rd times?  You should debug your code and see what is being returned.

Comment: It seems to only be executing the first binding operation, never reaches the breakpoints directly before 2nd and 3rd ones. Btw thanks for the help